# UpdatePanel inside Jquery dialog with form:first

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-dialog

I have this `dialog` with `updatepanel` inside, i'm trying to figure how to close it after `SelectedIndexChanged` fired

```
    <script>
$("[id*=senderBtnPopup]").click(function () {
            $("#senderDialog").dialog({
                title: "Sender Addresses",
                resizable: true,
                width: 1000,
                dialogClass: 'cssDialog'
            });
            //$("#senderDialog").parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
            return false;
        });
    </script>



<div id="senderDialog" style="display: none;">
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="senderUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="clientAddresses" CssClass="tablecs"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5"
                        OnPageIndexChanging="clientAddresses_PageIndexChanging" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="clientAddresses_Sorting"
                        DataKeyNames="Id,DefaultAddress" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="clientAddresses_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                        OnRowDataBound="clientAddresses_RowDataBound">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="ContactName" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PhoneNo" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="PhoneNo" />


                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="defaultAddressChk" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="defaultAddress_CheckedChanged" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>


protected void clientAddresses_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //some lines..
//this one doesn't work.
            senderUpdatePanel.Update();
            //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "dialog", "$(function(){closeDialog();});", true);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

add end request handle of your updatepanel in your client script:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
```

add a parameter to script manager in your SelectedIndexChanged server side handle

```
protected void clientAddresses_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //some lines..
  ScriptManager1.RegisterDataItem(clientAddresses, "OnSelectedIndexChanged");
}
```

manage the end request client side

```
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
            {
                 var dataItems = args.get_dataItems()['<%= clientAddresses.ClientID %>'];
                 if (dataItems != null && dataItems == 'OnSelectedIndexChanged')
                 //close here your modal
                 $(function(){closeDialog();});
            }
```